# wordpress plugin link in description opens in same window

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've decided to provide a  tag to setup videos in my plugin description.

In doing this, I've found WordPress does not respect the target="_blank" option.

Does anyone know a method of doing this?

Although it should be obvious, here is my code:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=the video code" target="_blank">this video playlist</a>
```

Comment: This code, as it is written, works just fine... it's probably more in the "context" to which you are putting this anchor tag.  Can you give more information, such as which plugin, which "description", any code you've written which outputs said string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so strange that in your WP not work `target="_blank`.
In the editor there is the command and give `target="_blank`.

So you can force it with:

```
 <a onclick="openInNewTab('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= video code ');">this video playlist</a>
```

This for me work every time.

Comment: No joy. Still does not work. I even tried this <a href="#" onClick="window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myvideoley', '_blank')">this video playlist</a> It seems that in the WordPress plugin information > Description area JS does not work.

Comment: It's strange, usually work well. Maybe you can try using a different tag like <div>  `<div href="#" onClick="window.open('youtube.com/watch?v=myvideoley';, '_blank')">text</div>`

Comment: I asked the WP core guys in Slack. WP blocks all markup period and options for A tags in the plugin description to avoid abuse. You solutions are good, but WP will not allow them and I don't want to develop outside the rules.